# AngularJS doesn't update view until refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am currently facing a problem, which has to do with views. I am making an app, which allows for users to create polls. When the poll that a user creates is submitted, I call a POST route to store it:

```
$scope.userVal = Auth.getCurrentUser();
$http.post('/api/users/update' + $scope.userVal._id, {polls: $scope.polls}).success(function(res){
          //console.log("res: ", res);
        });
```

Essentially, I get the user info,and use his id to store the new poll in a schema-defined value called polls.

Now, when a user clicks a button, I display the polls that were created via a ng-view:

```
$scope.pollView= function(){
        $scope.userVal2 = Auth.getCurrentUser();
        $scope.userVal2 = $scope.userVal2.polls;

        $scope.button = true;
     };
```

In the html, I simply iterate over $scope.userVal2. My problem comes when I try to view a newly created poll. The poll does not initially show up, but if I refresh the page, then it shows up. Is there any reason for this? Does this have to do with the async calls?

Any help would be appreciated!

edit:

Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('voteApp')
  .controller('WallCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Auth) {
     $scope.items = [];
     $scope.title;

     $scope.button = false; //set default to the new poll

     $scope.polls = [];

     $scope.items.push({id:1, upvotes:0, text:""});
     $scope.items.push({id:2, upvotes:0, text:""});

     $scope.addOptions = function(){
       $scope.items.push({id:$scope.items.length +1, upvotes:0, text:""});
     };

     $scope.process = function(name, values){
        $scope.polls.push({title:name, options:values});
        $scope.title = ""; //reset the values for the next poll
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.items.push({id:1, upvotes:0, text:""});
        $scope.items.push({id:2, upvotes:0, text:""});

        $scope.userVal = Auth.getCurrentUser();
        $http.post('/api/users/update' + $scope.userVal._id, {polls: $scope.polls}).success(function(res){
          //console.log("res: ", res);
        });
     };

     $scope.newView= function(){
        $scope.button = false;
     };

     $scope.pollView= function(){
        $scope.userVal2 = Auth.getCurrentUser().polls

        $scope.button = true;
     };

     $scope.delete = function(val){
       $scope.polls = $scope.polls.filter(function(returnableObjects){
              return returnableObjects.title !== val.title;
       });
     };
  });
```

html:

```
<div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>

<header class="hero-unit" id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <p class="lead">What would you like to do today?</p>
    <button ng-click="newView()" type="button" class="btn btn-lg newpoll">New Poll</button>
    <button ng-click="pollView()"type="button" class="btn btn-lg mypolls">My Polls</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div ng-show= "!button">
  <form name="form" ng-submit="process(title, items)">
    <h2 class="col-md-12 text-center">New Poll</h1>
    <h5 class="col-md-12 text-center">Name your poll.</h1>
    <input name="pollname" ng-model="title"type="text" class="form-control input_width" placeholder="Poll Name" required>
    <br>
    <h5 class="col-md-12 text-center">Options</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p>
          <input name = "{{item.id}}" ng-model="item.text" type="text" class="form-control input_width" placeholder="Option {{item.id}}" required>
        </p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button"ng-click="addOptions()" class="btn options" formnovalidate>More Options</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn button" validate>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div ng-show="button" >
    <br>
    <div ng-repeat="poll in userVal2">
      <div class="polldeco">
          {{poll[0].title}}
          <button class="btn buttondeco" ng-click="delete(poll)">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some comments on your code. In `$scope.pollView` why not have one line `$scope.userVal2 = Auth.getCurrentUser().polls` instead of 2?

Comment: Just so you know, I dont see any ng-view in your code. It looks like your using ng-show to update the view.

Comment: Instead of using `$scope.button`, try using an object like `$scope.poll.view` and set that to true and false. This is a weird thing that fixes a lot of problems. In general you should never just have a single property on the the scope. For instance `$scope.prop_name` <-- bad practice. `$scope.prop.name` <-- good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. `$scope.userVal2 = Auth.getCurrentUser().polls` is using the old version prior to the creation of a new poll? Maybe this could be changed to something like `Auth.getCurrentUser().then(...)`. Either way, ensure that the call to getCurrentUser() is returning new data.
2. `ng-view` is cached. When a template is initially requested, it gets stored in the `$templateCache`. If this template is rendered on the backend for display in as a partial (eg: ng-view) and it is not static content, then you will have to invalidate the cache to update the view.
3. Consider having the backend return the new poll from `$http.post('/api/users/update' ...)` and adding it to the list used by `ng-repeat`. Something like:

   ```
   $scope.process = function(name, values) {

       $scope.polls.push({title:name, options:values});
       ...
       $http.post('/api/users/update' + $scope.userVal._id, {polls: $scope.polls}).success(function(poll){
         $scope.polls.push(poll);
       });
    };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="poll in polls">
     <div class="polldeco">
         {{poll[0].title}}
         <button class="btn buttondeco" ng-click="delete(poll)">Delete</button>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```